# What does it mean if I add something with some column in Order by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

What I am asking is this query-

```
select * from emp order by sal + 2000;
```

Gives exactly same result as this query-

```
select * from emp order by sal;
```

Then what is the difference in terms of calculation?
What does `order by sal + 2000` mean?
How this influences the result?

Comment: it means nothing. you are just adding a value of `2000` for all `sal`.

Comment: @JohnWoo It does not add 2000 for all sal. It does exactly what order by sal would do. (Result perspective)

Comment: @szakwani i don't know what you mean by that. as far as i know it will add a value for the salary but it the new value for that `sal` column will not be displayed as the calculation has taken place on the `ORDER BY` clause not on the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: What I mean is the result would not show the addition. In your first comment you did not mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those queries do not give the same results if SAL is stored as a string.**

```
create table emp as
select  '90000' sal from dual union all
select '100000' sal from dual union all
select '110000' sal from dual;

select * from emp order by sal;

SAL
---
100000
110000
90000

select * from emp order by sal + 2000;

SAL
---
90000
100000
110000
```

I wish this was unusual but stringly-typed data models are far too common.

---

**Using an expression may change the execution plan and avoid an index.**

```
create table emp2(id number, sal number not null);
select 1 id,  90000 sal from dual union all
select 2 id, 100000 sal from dual union all
select 3 id, 110000 sal from dual;
create index emp2_idx on emp2(sal);

explain plan for select * from emp2 order by sal;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic'));

Plan hash value: 1831800775

------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     |
------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP2     |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN           | EMP2_IDX |
------------------------------------------------

explain plan for select * from emp2 order by sal + 2000;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic'));

Plan hash value: 2441141433

-----------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name |
-----------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |      |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP2 |
-----------------------------------
```

There are usually other, better ways to avoid an index, but some people use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following result set from your query, sorted (by default) in ascending order by the salary:

```
select name, salary from emp order by sal;

+------+--------+
| name | salary |
+------+--------+
| John | 10000  |
| Mike | 15000  |
| Joe  | 30000  |
+------+--------+
```

Here is the result set using `ORDER BY sal + 2000`:

```
select name, salary, (salary+2000) as new_salary from emp order by new_salary;

+------+--------+------------+
| name | salary | new_salary |
+------+--------+------------+
| John | 10000  | 12000      |
| Mike | 15000  | 17000      |
| Joe  | 30000  | 32000      |
+------+--------+------------+
```

Adding 2000 to the salary doesn't change the order you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
order by sal + 2000
```

Above line might be useless because it can perform either of two operations:

1. It might be adding 2000 to all salaries,then also the result will be same and all data will be in increasing order
2. "Additon" operation might not be allowed in "Order By" clause.

Answer (score 0):

Order by clause is used to order your result based on the column you specified
In Your case by default your result would be ordered by Sal is ASC (Ascending) order

Performing calculation in the order by has no effect on the result itself.